# MySQL - Grouping Time Ranges by Fifteen Minute Intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, time, intervals

So, I have a timekeeping table which tracks how much time my Employees are spending logged in to different states. It looks like so:

```
Employee_ID     Queue             StartTime            End Time
   121509      'Break'      2018-05-17 13:31:54  2018-05-17 13:47:02
   121509      'Working'    2018-05-17 13:47:04  2018-05-17 15:05:45
   121509      'Unavail.'   2018-05-17 15:05:46  2018-05-17 15:32:01
```

And so on. My goal is to aggregate the amount of time all Employees are spending in each Queue State (found by subtracting StartTime from EndTime) and to group that aggregation by fifteen minute intervals. What I *was* doing was this:

```
concat(
    time_format(convert_tz(StartTime,'UTC','America/Denver'),'%H'),
    ':',
    case
        when minute(convert_tz(StartTime,'UTC','America/Denver')) < 15
            then '00'
        when minute(convert_tz(StartTime,'UTC','America/Denver')) < 30
            then '15'
        when minute(convert_tz(StartTime,'UTC','America/Denver')) < 45
            then '30'
        else '45'
    end,
    ':00'
) as 'Interval',
```

However, by grouping that way, I realized that if I grouped things this way, then any time spent in a queue would be counted only for the *first* interval an Employee logged into, rather than splitting the time amongst all of the intervals enveloped by the time range laid out between StartTime and Endtime.

So, my question is: how do I group my data so that if a given time range goes over the fifteen minute interval it started in, it then starts counting for the *next* fifteen minute interval?

Example Output:

```
Employee_ID   Interval      Queue    QueueTime
   121509        13:30      'Break'   00:14:54
   121509        13:45      'Break'   00:02:02
   121509        13:45     'Working'  00:13:58
   121509        14:00     'Working'  00:15:00
   121509        14:15     'Working'  00:15:00
   121509        14:30     'Working'  00:02:58
   121509        14:30     'Unavail.' 00:08:13
   121509        14:30     'Break'    00:03:28
```

Comment: You could possibly get the date difference (`DATEDIFF(minute,StartTime,EndTime)`) of StartTime and EndTime. Then divide that by 15 to get how many 15 minute intervals each Employee had.

Comment: Can you add your expected output? Are you trying to generate a row fro every 15 minute period? Eg in an 8 hour day, you'd have 32 rows with time intervals set 15 minutes apart? Or are you trying to round the amount of time spend to 15 minute intervals?

Comment: Here is an SQL fiddle with your table schema populated: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4105f6

Comment: Ideally the output would be a list of fifteen minute intervals (15:00:00, 15:15:00, 15:30:00, etc.), along with the time the Employee spent in each queue in each interval. I've added an example above.

Comment: @StevenDay You're going to need to create an intervals table (with a row for each 15 minutes...eg `00,00`; `00,15`, up to `23,30`; `23,45`) and then query that table while pulling in the data from your queue table.  I don't have time to build an example, but hopefully that will get things progressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. It took some doing, but I figured it out with RToyo's help:

First: create a list of fifteen minute intervals:

```
        select 
        addtime(time('00:00:00'),sec_to_time(900 * (a.a + b.a * 10))) as 'IntervalStart',
        addtime(time('00:14:59'),sec_to_time(900 * (a.a + b.a * 10))) as 'IntervalEnd'
    from (
        select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
        cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    where
        addtime(time('00:00:00'),sec_to_time(900 * (a.a + b.a * 10))) between '06:00:00' and '18:45:00'
```

Next: join the Timekeeping table by testing the overlap between the StartTime and Endtime fields:

```
left join (     select 
        addtime(time('00:00:00'),sec_to_time(900 * (a.a + b.a * 10))) as 'Interval Start',
        addtime(time('00:14:59'),sec_to_time(900 * (a.a + b.a * 10))) as 'Interval End'
    from (
        select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
        cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    where
        addtime(time('00:00:00'),sec_to_time(900 * (a.a + b.a * 10))) between '06:00:00' and '18:45:00') as Intervals
on timekeepingtable.StartTime <= Intervals.IntervalStart
and timekeepingtable.EndTime >= Intervals.IntervalEnd
```

Then just modify the StartTime and EndTime fields to be bounded by the intervals:

```
        if(time(pgrp.StartTime) < Intervals.IntervalStart,Intervals.IntervalStart,time(pgrp.StartTime)) as 'Start Time',
    if(time(pgrp.EndTime) > Intervals.IntervalEnd, Intervals.IntervalEnd,time(pgrp.EndTime)) as 'End Time',
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you'll want to get the timestamp difference, and then group by employee and queue type. A query like this should work for you:

```
SELECT 
    Employee_ID,
    Queue,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
        StartTime,
        EndTime)) AS Time
FROM
    EmployeeTable
GROUP BY Employee_ID , Queue;
```

Comment: That *is* what I want, but grouped by fifteen minute intervals (i.e. 15:00:00, 15:15:00, 15:30:00, etc.) I've added an example of the output I'm looking for in the main question.